# $x ≡ a \pmod{m}, x ≡ b\pmod{n}, x ≡ c\pmod{r}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

What could be an example of three positive integers $m, n$, and $r$, and three integers $a, b$, and $c$ such that the $\mathrm{gcd}$ of $m, n$, and $r$ is $1$, but there is no simultaneous solution to

$x ≡ a \pmod{m}$

$x ≡ b\pmod{n}$

$x ≡ c\pmod{r}$

Comment: What's "simultaneous solution"? Do you mean that $a,b,c$ must be different from each other?

Comment: Hint: choose $\,m,n\,$ so $\,\gcd(m,n)\nmid a-b.\ $

Comment: @barakmanos Yes

Comment: If you mean the gcd of all three, just choose for two congruences such that it is impossible and the thrid so that gcd is 1.

Comment: @Megan when you say "the gcd of $m, n,$ and $r$ is $1$," do you mean $\gcd(m,n,r)=1$ or $\gcd(m,n) = \gcd(n,r) = \gcd(m,r) = 1$?

Comment: @anorton The first one