# Give an example of three positive integers m, n, and r

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can someone give an example of three **positive** integers m, n, and r, and three integers a, b, and c such that the GCD(m,n,r) = 1, but there is no simultaneous solution to:
x ≡ a (mod m)
x ≡ b (mod n)
x ≡ c (mod r)

Comment: $$m=n=2\,,\,\,r=3\;,\;\;x=0\pmod m\,,\,\,x=1\pmod n\;,\;\;x=0\pmod r\;$$

Comment: @Timbuc So basically: (m,n,r)=(2,2,3) and (a,b,c)=(0,1,0).

Comment: Yup, that's one option indeed.

Comment: Please don't ask exact duplicates of a prior question (here  [your question yesterday).](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1127088/242)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Try about setting $m=2, n=3$ and $r = 6$. Now, setting $a$ and $b$ will determine what $c$ must be in order for the system of equations to have a solution (and then $c$ can be set so that the solution does not exist).

Comment: Wouldn't a, b, and c be 2, 3, and 6?

Comment: @Megan Well, if you set $a,b,c$ to $2,3,6$, then your system has a solution. But if you set $a=b=0$, what happends if $c\neq 1$?

Comment: It wouldn't work

Comment: @Megan So, does this answer your question?

Comment: So basically you are saying that (m,n,r)=(2,3,6) and (a,b,c)=(0,0,1)?

Comment: @Megan Precisely.

Comment: But what does the statement, "no simultaneous solution" mean?

Comment: @Megan It means one value of $x$ that solves all three equations.

Comment: So in this case x = 0

Comment: @megan No, in this case, such an $x$ does not exist. That is what the question asks.